# What is SRID 0 for geometry columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

So I added geometry columns to a spatial table and using some of the msdn references I ended up specifying the SRID as 0 like so:

```
  update dbo.[geopoint] set GeomPoint = geometry::Point([Longitude], [Latitude], 0)
```

However, I believe this was a mistake, but before having to update the column, is 0 actually the default = 4326?  The query works as long as I specify the SRID as 0 on the query, but I'm getting weird results in comparison to the geography field I have...  SRID 0 does not exist in sys.spatial_reference_systems and I haven't been able to dig up any information on it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A SRID of 0 doesn't technically exist, it just means no SRID -- ie, the default if you forget to set it. So, technically, you can still perform distance, intersection and all other queries, so long as both sets of geometries have a SRID of 0. If you have one field of geometries with a SRID of 0 and another set with a SRID that actually exists, you will most likely get very strange results. I remember scratching my head once when not getting any results from a spatial query in exactly this situation and SQL Server did not complain, just 0 results (for what is is worth Postgis will actually fail, with a warning about non-matching SRIDs).

In my opinion, you should always explicitly set the SRID of your geometries (or geographies, which naturally will always be 4326), as not only does it prevent strange query results, but it means you can convert from one coordinate system to another. Being able to convert on the fly from lat/lon (4326), to Spherical Mercator (3857), as used in Google Maps/Bing, which is in meters, or some local coordinate system, such as 27700, British National Grid, also in meters, can be very useful. SQL Server does not to my knowledge support conversion from one SRID to another, but as spatial types are essentially CLR types, there are .NET libraries available should you ever need to do so, see [Transform/ Project a geometry from one SRID to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502063/transform-project-a-geometry-from-one-srid-to-another) for an example.

If you do decide to change you geometries, you can do something like:

```
UPDATE your_table SET newGeom = geometry::STGeomFromWKB(oldGeom.STAsBinary(), SRID);
```

which will create a new column or to do it in place:

```
UPDATE geom SET geom.STSrid=4326;
```

where 4326 is just an example SRID.

There is a good reference for SRIDs at http://spatialreference.org/, though this is essentially the same information as you find in sys.spatial_reference_systems.

Comment: Did you just accept then unaccept the this answer (your prerogative, obviously). I ask because my edit vanished at the same time, so I don't know if there is a temporary blip with SO, or if you decided the answer is lacking in some way.

Comment: Thanks, recode the column it is then :-) -- i did accept and un-accept then re-accept because i was going to post a follow up but i dont have any data to ask my next question -- the reason i added the geometry column in the first place is i was getting really strange results on running multiple point radii counts using geography, and the results were literally 10% of that using geometry (with srid 0, mind you..)... but I'll wait until i reconvert the column.

Comment: I use Postgis more these days, which is fussier than SQL Server, but also allows reprojection on the fly. I have a table of 450 million rows which I forgot to set the SRID on when I created it. It is still causing me pain, as I don't have space to rewrite the table during the update. I'll get round to it, but moral of story, is always set the SRID :-)

Comment: While setting a SRID is definitely a good idea, the question of geometry vs geography is another question. I suggest you read this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx, if you haven't already.

Comment: Understood, once I have these re-coded I'll follow up if I'm still seeing wonky results..  If I'm in +/- 5% for my purposes that's okay, with the 0 SRID i was at +120% :P.

Comment: [MSDN Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895373(v=sql.105).aspx "Geometry Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes") claims that: 
> To return a non-null result, geometry1 and geometry2 must have the same spatial reference identifier (SRID). Otherwise, the method returns NULL.

Comment: *"but it means you can convert from one coordinate system to another"* SQL Server to this very day can't transform/reproject from one SRID to another, so I think think this answer is off the mark. But yeah, PostGIS is awesome and it can!

Answer (score 1):

SRIDs are a way to take into account that the distances that you're measuring on aren't on a flat, infinite plane but rather an oblong spheroid. They make sense for the geography data type, but not for geometry. So, if you're doing geographic calculations (as your statement of "in comparison to the geography field I have"), create geography points instead of geometry points. In order to do calculations on any geospatial data (like "find the distance from this point to this other point"), the SRID of all the objects involved need to be the same.

TL;DR: Is the point on the Cartesian plane? Use geometry. Is the point on the globe? Use geography.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not correct.  There are STSrid methods for both gemetry and geography (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933851.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx).  There are plenty of examples of projected SRIDs that use a cartesian plane, e.g. UTM, State Planar, etc.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you can use geography for projected coordinates (as well as geometry), but you can not use geometry for geodetic coordinates.

Comment: I'm willing to be wrong here. But in the spirit of education, where can one find definitions of the SRIDs in the geometry examples? That is, where is the WKT for SRIDs 13 & 23? They're certainly not in sys.spatial_reference_systems and a google search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Yeah those are not valid SRIDs, I would those are just custom SRIds for example.  I did an experiment to check, and I was actually able to insert a geographic SRID (4326 in this case) into a geometry column, which is incredibly strange to me.  However this does show that what I said above is partially incorrect.  I would still contest though your assertion that it doesn't make sense to use an SRID for a geometry type, as any operations in a projected SRID are just plain old Euclidean geometry.