# Incorrect Distances When Comparing geography values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gis

I have a SQL database set up containing a number of fields one of which is a geography field called Coordinates. I have a need to search for all rows that are within a certain radius and to do that I am using the query

```
DECLARE @CurrentLocation geography; 
SET @CurrentLocation  = geography::Point(-84.505562, 39.137706, 4326)

SELECT * , Coordinates.STDistance(@CurrentLocation) AS Distance FROM tParkingLot
WHERE Coordinates.STDistance(@CurrentLocation )<= 200000
```

which gives me the following results 
[image]

the first row is returning as expected as I used those coordinates as my center. However, when measuring the other two lots on google maps I find that the results should be closer to 1133.246 for row 2 and 74673.56 for row 3

I can see from other stackoverflow results that a common mistake is to insert data as lat/lon as opposed to lon/lat however I have already made and corrected that mistake and I cannot determine why I am getting distance results that are so far off from the actual measurements.

Comment: Most people here prefer results as formatted text

Comment: Could you give the lat and long values of the points from your screenshot?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25190899/6305294 , i.e. Google uses a different coordinate system.

Comment: So if im understanding this correctly I need to find a way to save the SRID as 3857 rather then 4326?

Comment: Test it first, with suggested SRD values before you do any conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the order of latitude and longitude. Geography world traditionally uses `(lat, lon)` order, SQL world defined `(x, y)` order, which usually means `(lon, lat)` order.

Microsoft SQL Server Point constructor made confusing compromise: they use `(x, y)` order for Geometry, but `(lat, lon)` order for Geography:

```
Point ( Lat, Long, SRID )  [1]
```

Since your points are in Cincinnati rather than Antartica, swap argument order.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017