# Change projection in MSSQL for web mapping (Leaflet,Openlayer, OpenStreetMaps, GoogleAPI, ...) to WSG48 or any other format

Tags: sql-server, leaflet, spatial, map-projections, sqlgeography

I have some WKT/WKB data in the MSSQL server like this and would like to show them on the map with the help of leaflet, Openlayer, OpenStreetMaps, or GoogleAPI. My data look likes this:

```
POLYGON ((1736946.0983 5923253.9175, 1736895.6852 5923333.9451, 1736936.0082 5923356.6991, ......))
```

in this format

```
 EPSG:2193
```

as shown below

[image]
and would like to convert them to

```
  WGS48 or EPSG:4326
```

I am trying to add them to leaflet, and seems that I need to convert this data to an appropriate format like this:

```
[[42.353770, -71.103606], [42.355447, -71.104475], [42.362681, -71.089830], [42.361829, -71.079230]]
```

Unfortuanlty, I am not sure how to do this conversion.

I have tries some approaches like these

[[1.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200746/convert-geography-to-geometry-sql-server-2008r2). Error:

```
 A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
 System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

[[2.]](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx)  Query:

```
select  GEOGRAPHY::STPolyFromText ([stastxt],4326) from mytable
Error:
 A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
 System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

[[3.]](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/splitting-multi-geometries-into-single-geometries/)
 No success

[4.] I am able to see this data as a layer in GeoServer when I set the `Declared SRS` as `EPSG:2193`

After doing more study on this issue, 
***the question is:***

Can I do this transformation merely in MSSQL server or Leaflet or I need to use some other tools like Proj4net and replace '(' with '['?

Comment: You have to reproject those coordinates into WGS84 (EPSG:3857) latitude and longitude or [define the matching CRS](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#crs). What area are these coordinates from?

Comment: Thanks Chrki, New Zealand, I have added more info to my question, what about converting '(' in MSSQL to '[' in leaflet?

Comment: When you say you have WKT in the database, I'm assuming it's just stored as text (based on your attempts above to convert it into a geography instance). From where did you get it? It looks like geometry data (as opposed to geography) to me.

Comment: Yes, that is true Ben, I got it from ([Geom].[STAsText]())

Comment: I have adjusted my question as found more information. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I developed an interesting solution, I will explain my solution step by step as I am sure other faces similar problems.

The first point is to know which projection the data is (src) and which projection you would like to have (dst). Usually, dst is `EPSG:4326`, `EPSG:3857`, or `WGS48`. For this solution, I needed to find the correct mathematics behind that, so I used this website
https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/
to find the correct format for src and dst (If you are familiar with `R` it has a function for this also called `spTransform`). Another reason is that I gonna use Proj4 component for this conversion. Another critical step is conversion to GeoJson as these web maps can read GeoJson files. I did not want to write my data to physical GeoJson files, so I did the conversion on demand in MSSQL (No need to write it somewhere as a GeoJson file).

1. Make a library in C#, and get a dll.
2. Import this to MSSQL
3. Enjoy it

The code for the first part: **Install [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial) via Nugget**

```
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class classval
{
    public string line;
    public string src;
    public string dst;

    public classval(string line, string src, string dst)
    {
        this.line = line;
        this.src = src;
        this.dst = dst;
    }



}

public class CLRProjection
{
    private static IEnumerable<classval> ConvertedEnumerable(string line, string src, string dst)
    {
        return new List<classval> { new classval(line, src, dst) };
    }

    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
    public static IEnumerable ToLatLong(string Geometry, string src, string dst)
    {
        return ConvertedEnumerable(Geometry, src, dst);
    }

    private static void FillRow(Object classvalobj, out string Geometry, out string srcprj, out string dstprj)
    {
    
       classval geomobj = (classval)classvalobj;
        string _geometry = geomobj.line; //"POLYGON ((1736946.0983 5923253.9175,....))";
    string proj4_src = geomobj.src; //"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ";
    string proj4_dst = geomobj.dst;//"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace(",", " , ");
    _geometry = _geometry.Remove(0, _geometry.IndexOf('('));
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace("(", "[ ");
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace(")", " ]");
    string[] splitbycomma = _geometry.Split(',');
    
    foreach (var itembycomma in splitbycomma)
        {

            string tmpitem = itembycomma;
            tmpitem = tmpitem.Replace('[', ' ');
            tmpitem = tmpitem.Replace(']', ' ');
            tmpitem = tmpitem.Trim();
            string[] splitbyspace = tmpitem.Split(' ');
            for (int ibs = 0; ibs < splitbyspace.Length - 1; ibs++)
            {

                double[] x = { double.Parse(splitbyspace[ibs]) };
                double[] y = { double.Parse(splitbyspace[ibs + 1]) };
                double[] z = new double[x.Length];
                //rewrite xy array for input into Proj4
                double[] xy = new double[2 * x.Length];
                int ixy = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= x.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    xy[ixy] = x[i];
                    xy[ixy + 1] = y[i];
                    z[i] = 0;
                    ixy += 2;
                }
                double[] xy_geometry = new double[xy.Length];
                Array.Copy(xy, xy_geometry, xy.Length);


                
                DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo src =
                    DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(proj4_src);
                DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo trg =
                    DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(proj4_dst);

                DotSpatial.Projections.Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, src, trg, 0, x.Length);


                ixy = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= x.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                _geometry = _geometry.Replace(xy_geometry[ixy].ToString() + " ", "[" + xy[ixy + 1].ToString() + " , ");
                _geometry = _geometry.Replace(xy_geometry[ixy + 1].ToString() + " ", xy[ixy].ToString() + " ] ");
                _geometry = _geometry.Replace("- ", "-");
                    string tt = (i + 1 + " " + xy[ixy] + " " + xy[ixy + 1]);

                    ixy += 2;
                }

            }
        }
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace("  ", " ");
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace(" [ ", "[");
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace(" ] ", "]");
    _geometry = _geometry.Replace(" , ", ",");
    srcprj = proj4_src;
    dstprj = proj4_dst;
    Geometry = _geometry;
    }

}
```

The code for the second part (Inside MSSQL)

```
  ALTER DATABASE test SET trustworthy ON
 CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRFunctionAssem
 FROM N'C:\Users\...\bin\Debug\Convertor_Projection.dll'
 WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
 GO


 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ToLatLong(@Geometry nvarchar(max), @src nvarchar(max),@dst nvarchar(max))
 RETURNS TABLE
 ( _geom  nvarchar(max) ,srcprj  nvarchar(max) ,dstprj  nvarchar(max) 
) with execute as caller
AS
 EXTERNAL NAME CLRFunctionAssem.[CLRProjection].[ToLatLong]
```

MSSQL code

```
 SELECT       
  [parcelid]
  ,[Geom1]
  ,[stastxt]
   ,conv._geom
   
 FROM [test].[dbo].[TEST_JSON] as a  CROSS APPLY dbo.ToLatLong (a.
[stastxt],'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs','+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs') as conv
 where [stastxt] is not null
```

MSSQL2016 has JSON [functiality](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/01/05/json-in-sql-server-2016-part-1-of-4/), while older versions do not have this ability.

Output
[image]

Resources which helped me are:

[1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-valued-clr-function-in-sql-server-2005/),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502063/transform-project-a-geometry-from-one-srid-to-another),[3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the plugin [Proj4Leaflet](https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/api/) to do the conversion in Leaflet.

Comment: This is a faster solution, compared to mine, but does not change the ( to [ and also does not change the long and lat order.